# Creating and linking a new table in the backend using VBA in the frontend

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Im using VBA in my Access frontend to create a new table in my Access backend, then I link the table to my frontend.
The table and index is created successfully, but I keep getting the same error saying that the backend is in use by another user when I try to create a linked table in the front end. How can I fix this. I have done this several times in the past on this project, but all of a sudden it does not want to work anymore.

I have tried creating the table in the backend first, then adding values to the table, then closing the connection to the backend database and reconnecting to it, then to transfer the link to the front end. No GO, Same error over and over.
I am the only person accessing both files. The backend does not even show a locked file, but still it says that I cannot access it.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
On Err GoTo errExit
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim DB_PATH As String
Dim strConn As String

    DB_PATH = DLookup("BackendDirectory", "Link_Save")
    strConn = "MS Access;PWD=" & BE_PASSWORD & ";DATABASE=" & DB_PATH
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase(DB_PATH, True, False, strConn)

'Create table tbl_Client_Type

        dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE tbl_Client_Type (Client_Type_ID COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY, " & _
                                        "Client_Type TEXT(100) NOT NULL);"

        dbs.Execute "CREATE INDEX Client_Type_ID ON tbl_Client_Type (Client_Type_ID ASC);"

        DoEvents: 
        dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Client_Type (Client_Type) VALUES ('Motor')"
        dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Client_Type (Client_Type) VALUES ('Sail')"
        dbs.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Client_Type (Client_Type) VALUES ('Other')"
        DoEvents:

        'dbs.Close
        'Set dbs = Nothing
        'Set dbs = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(DB_PATH, True, False, strConn)
        DoEvents:

        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", DB_PATH, acTable, "tbl_Client_Type", "tbl_Client_Type"

        DoEvents:
        RefreshLinkedTable "tbl_Client_Type"
        Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing

errExit:
   Debug.Print Err.Number
    Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

**Runtime error 3045
"Could not use 'Database', file already in use**

The file is not in use and no laccdb lock file

Comment: with the errExit statement before the `Set dbs = Nothing` statement. you are probably still holding onto the dbs instance. Move the `dbs = nothing` till after the `errExit:` line. Also, you should only skip errors on a single line that you know will cause an error. Otherwise, you can get all kinds of bad results. Finally, try closing out access completely and reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the database *shared*:

```
Set dbs = OpenDatabase(DB_PATH, False, False, strConn)
```